# How can I run a docker image of my local machine on my office server?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, devops, remote-server

I have an angular project which is built as a docker image in my local machine. Now I need to run it on my office server. How can I do it? I don't have superuser permission also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like:

a. You will need someone who does have SU permission to install Docker EE on the server. Docker EE, installed on Windows, will be in windows container mode, if you actually want linux containers, get a linux server.

b. You will need them to configure the server for remote access by generating and adding the necessary certificates to the dockerd service command line and exposing docker on port 2376.

c. You can now create a docker context on your desktop with a client certificate (also provided). and can with that use `docker-compose -c my-context up` to deploy directly to the server with no direct access requried.

Comment: docker run --add-host=ssh:100.x.x.x -p 4211:4211 --rm -it image_name

I used this command and I didn't get any error. How can I check whether the image is working or not on the remote server? Can I use 100.x.x.x:4211 to view my web application?

Comment: if its running on the remote server with its port exposed then it should be available on the remote servers ip and port. But --add-host is not making docker run execute against the remote host - that makes docker add an entry to the containers dns. to execute a docker command against a remote docker using ssh: `docker -H ssh://10.x.x.x run ...`

Comment: The image is not running on the remote server. But, I'm trying to deploy and run it on my office server from my machine. 
Suppose you have an image on your laptop and you have to deploy and run it on 100.150.22.142 with port 4211, which command you will use to make work?